# Как вывести название окна (не exe и не заголовок) отдельного приложения

Tags: c#, winforms

В общем мое приложение собирает информацию о всех процессах имеющих окно, но оно у меня работает указывая название exe файла. Так как не все программы имеют exe такого же названия как и сама программа я столкнулся со сложностями. Изменил значит я немного код и теперь мне показывается заголовок окна, но это тоже неудобно так как часто они очень длинные и о программе там написано всего 1-2 слова. Можно ли как-нибудь вывести само название программы каким-либо другим способом?

```
processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
.Where(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero).ToArray()
```

Вот пример кода, который показывает заголовки окна.

Comment: Что значит `само название программы`? Я могу exe файл назвать `A.exe`, окно назвать `B`, в главное меню положить ярлык `C`, а на рабочий стол ярлык `D`

Comment: Я не знаю, имеет же приложение какое-то имя, например, когда я пишу в поиске yandex мне показывает yandex, а не browser.exe и не заголовок окна тоже.

Comment: Если вам надо то, что в поиске ищется - вам надо искать все ярлыки в меню юзера. Ярлык может на что угодно указывать.